# Write hex numbers stored as strings to hex file directly in Java?

Tags: java, hex, output

I'm writing a small assembler in Java that converts ARM assembly code to hex file that will be executed by a virtual ARM CPU on FPGA.

For example

```
Sub R0, r15,    R15
Add R2,    R0, #5
aDD R3, R0, #12
SUB R7, r3, #9
```

will be translated to machine(hex) code as

```
E04F000F
E2802005
E280300C
E2437009
```

which are stored as strings line by line in a string array `output` in my code.

So how can I write the machine code to hex file which is **exactly** what it **literally** is? Instead of being encoded as text.

So when I open the output file with tools like Hexeditor it will show the encoding exactly as (without newline sign of course...)

```
E0 4F 00 0F E2 80 20 05 E2 80 30 0C E2 43 70 09
```

Currently I tried:

```
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("hexcode.hex");
        for (String s : output) {
            int value = Integer.decode(s);
            os.write(value);                
        }
        os.close();
```

but it gives me errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:"E04F000F"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:740)
at java.lang.Integer.decode(Integer.java:1197)
at assembler.Assembler.main(Assembler.java:220)
```

Any help? Million thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use `Integer.parseInt(s, 16)` instead of `Integer.decode(string)`

"16" tells it it is a hex-string